# How to get a percentage of a SQL query result

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have the below query which works just fine and gives me the the total fund value of an investment, however I would now like to extract a percentage of the result and not sure how. Let's say that the result of the below query is 100, I would like then to change the query to calculate what 30% is of 100 and to provide the the result as the output.

```
SELECT ROUND (SUM (NVL ((a.units * p.price) / 100, a.amt)), 2) totalfundvalue
  FROM (
            SELECT b1,
                   REF,
                   schme,
                   contdef,
                   cont,
                   fundcode,
                   fund,
                   SUM (rrr) amt,
                   SUM (ttt) units
              FROM hist
             WHERE     b1 = 'SL'
                   AND eee <= SYSDATE
                   AND refno = '5656'
                   AND schme = 'M'
          GROUP BY b1,
                   refno,
                   schme,
                   contdef,
                   cont,
                   fundcode,
                   fund
       ) a,
       (
          SELECT b1,
                 fundcode,
                 fund,
                 www price
            FROM (
                    SELECT b1,
                           fundcode,
                           fund,
                           www,
                           qqq,
                           seqno,
                           MAX (qqq) OVER (PARTITION BY b1, fundcode, fund) maxdate,
                           MAX (seqno)
                              OVER (PARTITION BY b1,
                                                 fundcode,
                                                 fund,
                                                 qqq) maxseqno
                      FROM funddef
                     WHERE     b1 = 'SL'
                           AND qqq <= SYSDATE
                 )
           WHERE     qqq = maxdate
                 AND seqno = maxseqno
       ) p,
       conttype  c,
       mp_fund   f,
       basic     b
 WHERE     a.b1 = p.b1(+)
       AND a.b1 = f.b1(+)
       AND a.b1 = b.b1
       AND a.b1 = c.b1(+)
       AND a.fundcode = p.fundcode(+)
       AND a.fundcode = f.fundcode(+)
       AND a.fund = p.fund(+)
       AND a.conttype = c.conttype(+)
       AND a.REF = b.REF
       AND NVL (a.units * p.price, a.amt) > 0
```

Comment: Please format your code to be readable, and make a [mre] as per this advice; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Query returns a single value (100, as you said). What kind of percentage do you expect to get out of it? Will you pass that *percentage* value as a parameter? Because, as I understood it, that's just `totalfundvalue * PERCENTAGE_PARAMETER_VALUE / 100` (round it, if you want).

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say that the result of the below query is 100, I would like then to change the query to calculate what 30% is of 100 and to provide the the result as the output.

Multiply by `30/100` or, equivalently, `0.3`.

```sql
SELECT 0.3 * ROUND (SUM (NVL ((a.units * p.price) / 100, a.amt)), 2)
         AS thirty_percent_of_totalfundvalue
FROM   rest_of_your_query
```